# Joomla installation not working

Tags: joomla

I am trying to install `joomla 2.5` but in `step-4`, which is database, there is a some problem occur so that I can not install it.
what is problem?
I am using wamp.

Comment: What PHP and MySQL version is your Wampserver using? Define "not working". Does it freez? Are you getting any errors? Did you try installing Joomla 3.2 instead?

Comment: mysql version 5.6.12 PHP Version 5.4.16                               No I am not getting any error.

Comment: joomla 3.2 not supporting virtuemart so that i am using joomla 2.5

Comment: Did you create a database and user before trying to install Joomla? If so, are you sure you have typed in the dstabase, name, username and password correctly?

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Installing_Joomla

Answer (score 1):

Please install new version of Wamp because I have use wamp and I install joomla 2.5 and joomla 3.0 easily in my wamp server2.4.

Please Follow this step in step 4:
 1) Select Databse type : mysql
 2) Hostname : localhost
 3) username : root
 4) Password:  (blank)
 5) Databse name: xyz
 6) Old databse process : backup

Comment: The OP is already using the latest version of wampserver. (2.4)